# Function member pointers

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have something similar to

Base.h

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

class Base
{
virtual Base* createNew() = 0;
}

#endif
```

D.h

```
#ifndef D_H
#define D_H

#include "Base.h"

class D : public Base
{
virtual Base* createNew();
}

#endif
```

D.cpp

```
#include "D.h"
Base* D:createNew()
{
return new D();
}
```

main.cpp

```
typedef Base* (Base::*FP)(void);

#include "D.h"

void create(FP pointer)
{
//empty for now
}

int main()
{
create(&D::createNew); //This doesnt work =s?

}
```

I am extremely confused why this doesn't work can anybody give me some advice on what I should be doing????

Ps. Sorry if the code doesnt run I put it there for example sakes just to show you what I was doing

Comment: Please dont post code for *example sakes*, You have a specific problem so post the specific code which reproduces your problem you are facing.

Comment: That would be pointless unless you really expect me to upload 20classes... I have sumed it up to this exactly. So you dont see code that is pointless to my question. And this does show the problem I am facing just in its simplist form.

Comment: Als meant minimal example (compilation can fail). See [how to ask questions a smart way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code)

Comment: createNew function should be static so that it can be called without an instance. Isn't it FactoryPattern that you are trying to accomplish ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous syntax problems in your code;

- Base::createNew() is private and virtual.
- Neither class declaration has a terminating `;`.
- D:createNew() should be D::createNew().
  ...

I think what you're referring to though is that taking a member function pointer and passing it to a method won't work.

The problem is that you're taking a method that can only be called with a `D` and trying to pass it as a pointer to a function that can take a `Base` that is not necessarily a `D`. The reverse would work, (ie passing `Base::createNew()` to a function taking a `D::createNew()` since `Base::createNew()` always exists in a D, not the other way around)

Comment: Thats a shame I guess I will have to think of another solution thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 create(&Base::createNew);
```

After all, create wants a Base::* pointer to member, not a D::*.

I don't think there is covariance across inheritance lines for pointers-to-member; `Base::*` type pointer-to-member is incompatible with a `D::*` type pointer to member.

However, you can still call the `D` virtual function through the `Base` pointer to member on a `D` object. A `D` really is a kind of `Base`, and so you can do `dinst->*pmemb` where `pmemb` is a &Base::createNew`.

#### Also ...

Your `D::createNew` can return `D *`. This "covariance" in the return type of a virtual function is allowed in C++. It is still the same virtual function which overrides the one in the `Base` which returns `Base *`.  When you're calling `D::createNew` directly, you might sometimes appreciate getting a `D *` pointer so you can work with the `D` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing following trivial compiler errors in your code,

1. Missing `;` after `class` body
2. Changing `D:createNew` to `D::createNew`
3. Making `D::createNew` in `public` specifier

Your code doesn't compile at, `create(&D::createNew)`. Because it's not convertible. The error message is clear:

```
error: cannot convert ‘Base* (D::*)()’ to ‘FP {aka Base* (Base::*)()}’
```

**Edit**: One way is to use `template` evaluation, if you decide to do it at compile time.

```
template<typename ReturnType, typename Class>
void create(ReturnType (Class::*pointer)())
{
}
```

Call it as:

```
create<Base*, D>(&D::createNew);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i was really wonder if there was a way to pass D or any other inheritended classes as the pointer?

Comment: @ChrisCondy, it is possible at compile time using `template`. If it's feasible for you then see my edited answer.

Comment: @ChrisCondy Put that in the question.